# Triac dimmer component

Tags: components, triac, dimmer

I was looking for a way to dim a regular light bulb in a circuit.
With the help of this site, I learned that using (variable) resistors would dim the light, but eat up electricity in the form of heat.

What I needed was a triac dimmer. I have been looking for a triac dimmer component, but failed to find anything that would fit my needs. What I'm looking for is something that is small and where a knob can be attached, much like a potentiometer.

Does this kind of component exist and how is it called? Maybe this kind of component is too big, and does not exist as a "kind of potentiometer".

Beginner questions from an absolute beginner. All help is much appreciated!

More info:

- this question is about AC power
- I want to make a lamp on a small block of wood with a knob to dim the light

Comment: A big amount of households seem to have such an item installed in their walls or on some lamps...

Comment: AC or DC power?

Comment: AC, I'll update my answser

Comment: if u want to buy means the most product will be  like wall mount, like fan speed controller,if u want to embedded into your circuit means need to design ZERO CROSSING DETECTION with triac

Comment: A normal house light dimmer sounds just what you need.  Some of them do have a minimum wattage, though. What wattage lamp is it?

Comment: I need to double check, but I think 40W

Answer (score 1):

This is as small as a dimmer can get. I think this fill all of your requirements and is rated for 300W. 
http://www.grandbrass.com/SearchShowItem.cfm?ItemNumber=DIB300

[image]